# Resolving variables

Tags: android

I've taken a program from a book as a template. In `activity_main.xml` I have:

```
android:id="@+id/contactID"//and 
android:id="@+id/contactName"
```

both are specified in separate text views.

Then in mainActivity.java I have:

```
int[] views = new int[] {R.id.contactName, R.id.contactID};
```

Neither variable is defined in the java file which looks odd to me, but that's what the book says...and eclipse says neither variable can be resolved or is a field so it won't compile. It's the correct contentView.

I'm guessing that R is supposed to pick these up when compiling - it doesn't. I've tried cleaning with no joy. Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your import. remove `android.R` if its imported. And import your R.  Also make sure that  you do NOT have any errors in your xmls, or else your R will not be generated.

Comment: Thanks a lot - there was a typo in my xml file. Much appreciated!